# continuous distribution function is absolutely continuous

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I read an article saying that if the quantile function of a r.v. $Y$ is strictly increasing, i.e., $Q_Y(p)$ is strictly increasing in $p$, then $Y$ has absolutely continuous distributions.

However, I suspect whether it is correct. I know that its distribution function must be continuous, but how can it be absolutely continuous?